# How to acces exit code previous command on Windows when conditional execution is used?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I would like to feed the exit code (not `stdout` or `stderr`) into a command on Windows cmd.

```
c:\>echo Initial command that exits with 0 && cmd /C "exit 0"

c:\>cmd /c "exit 1" || echo Error level: %errorlevel%, but should be 1
Error level: 0, but should be 1
c:\>cmd /c "exit 2" || echo Error level: %errorlevel%, but should be 0
Error level: 1, but should be 2
```

It seems that `%errorlevel%` is evaluated instantly. Is there a similar way as `$?` in `bash`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `%errorlevel%` in `cmd /c "exit 1" || echo Error level: %errorlevel%` line is  expanded at parse time. Read [Delayed Expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) article:

> *Delayed Expansion will cause variables within a batch file to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time*.

```
d:\bat> cmd /V:ON /c "(cmd /C exit 5) || echo Error level: !errorlevel!"
Error level: 5

d:\bat> cmd /V:ON /c "(cmd /C exit 1) || echo Error level: !errorlevel!"
Error level: 1

d:\bat> cmd /V:ON /c "(cmd /C exit -1) || echo Error level: !errorlevel!"
Error level: -1
```

Answer (score 0):

To feed at least the success or failure (but not the actual errorlevel) of the first command into the second command:

```
cmd1 && cmd2 0 || cmd2 1
```

This might not be exactly an answer to the original question, but it helped me with a use case that seems related to the original question:

```
@mvn.cmd %* && playsound success || playsound failure
```

As an alternative to

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
call mvn.cmd %* & playsound !errorlevel!
```